# Очередь в Windows Form

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, очередь

Такая вот задача: "С помощью Windows From реализовать очередь , которая будет добавлять элементы, удалять первый, выводить первый, выводить последний и выводить размер очереди". И стала такая проблема, объявление в Windows Form отличается от обычного с++ и на простое `queue<string> myQueue;`, компилятор возмущается. Пробовал сделать так : `Queue<System::String> numbers = new Queue<System::String>;` , но тоже не подошло. Нужна помощь профессионалов.
Заголовочный файл.h

```
#pragma once 
#include <queue>
#include <string>
 
namespace Program {
 
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
 
    public ref class MenuForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    private:
        Queue<System::String> numbers = new Queue<System::String>;
    public:
        MenuForm(void)
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        }
    protected:
        ~MenuForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    public: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ addSave;
    public: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox_Input;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox^ groupBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^ checkBox1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^ checkBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox^ checkBox3;
    public: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^ textBox1;
    private: System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;
#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        void InitializeComponent(void){
            this->addSave = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->textBox_Input = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->groupBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::GroupBox());
            this->checkBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
            this->checkBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
            this->checkBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::CheckBox());
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->groupBox1->SuspendLayout();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // addSave
            // 
            this->addSave->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::Gold;
            this->addSave->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
            this->addSave->Location = System::Drawing::Point(437, 34);
            this->addSave->Name = L"addSave";
            this->addSave->Size = System::Drawing::Size(101, 30);
            this->addSave->TabIndex = 1;
            this->addSave->Text = L"Add";
            this->addSave->UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            this->addSave->UseWaitCursor = true;
            this->addSave->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MenuForm::addSave_Click);
            // 
            // textBox_Input
            // 
            this->textBox_Input->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
            this->textBox_Input->Location = System::Drawing::Point(6, 34);
            this->textBox_Input->Multiline = true;
            this->textBox_Input->Name = L"textBox_Input";
            this->textBox_Input->Size = System::Drawing::Size(425, 30);
            this->textBox_Input->TabIndex = 2;
            this->textBox_Input->UseWaitCursor = true;
            // 
            // groupBox1
            // 
            this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->textBox_Input);
            this->groupBox1->Controls->Add(this->addSave);
            this->groupBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
            this->groupBox1->Name = L"groupBox1";
            this->groupBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(544, 86);
            this->groupBox1->TabIndex = 6;
            this->groupBox1->TabStop = false;
            this->groupBox1->Text = L"Ввод строки в очередь";
            this->groupBox1->UseWaitCursor = true;
            // 
            // checkBox1
            // 
            this->checkBox1->AutoSize = true;
            this->checkBox1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
            this->checkBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 122);
            this->checkBox1->Name = L"checkBox1";
            this->checkBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(186, 20);
            this->checkBox1->TabIndex = 7;
            this->checkBox1->Text = L"Изъять первый элемент";
            this->checkBox1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->checkBox1->UseWaitCursor = true;
            // 
            // checkBox2
            // 
            this->checkBox2->AutoSize = true;
            this->checkBox2->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
            this->checkBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 148);
            this->checkBox2->Name = L"checkBox2";
            this->checkBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(202, 20);
            this->checkBox2->TabIndex = 8;
            this->checkBox2->Text = L"Получить первый элемент";
            this->checkBox2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->checkBox2->UseWaitCursor = true;
            // 
            // checkBox3
            // 
            this->checkBox3->AutoSize = true;
            this->checkBox3->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.75F, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Regular, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
            this->checkBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 174);
            this->checkBox3->Name = L"checkBox3";
            this->checkBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(194, 20);
            this->checkBox3->TabIndex = 9;
            this->checkBox3->Text = L"Вывести размер очереди";
            this->checkBox3->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->checkBox3->UseWaitCursor = true;
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Font = (gcnew System::Drawing::Font(L"Microsoft Sans Serif", 12, System::Drawing::FontStyle::Bold, System::Drawing::GraphicsUnit::Point,
                static_cast<System::Byte>(204)));
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 200);
            this->textBox1->Multiline = true;
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(425, 30);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 10;
            this->textBox1->UseWaitCursor = true;
            // 
            // MenuForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->BackColor = System::Drawing::SystemColors::ActiveCaption;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(568, 264);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->checkBox3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->checkBox2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->checkBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->groupBox1);
            this->Cursor = System::Windows::Forms::Cursors::WaitCursor;
            this->FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::Fixed3D;
            this->MaximizeBox = false;
            this->Name = L"MenuForm";
            this->SizeGripStyle = System::Windows::Forms::SizeGripStyle::Hide;
            this->StartPosition = System::Windows::Forms::FormStartPosition::CenterScreen;
            this->Text = L"Работа с очередью";
            this->TopMost = true;
            this->TransparencyKey = System::Drawing::Color::Black;
            this->UseWaitCursor = true;
            this->groupBox1->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->groupBox1->PerformLayout();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();
 
        }
#pragma endregion
private: System::Void addSave_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e);
};
}
```

Исполняемый файл.cpp

```
#include "MenuForm.h"
 
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
 
[STAThreadAttribute]
void main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 
    Program::MenuForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
 
}
 
System::Void Program::MenuForm::addSave_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    myQueue.push(textBox_Input);
}
```

Неужели в windows form не внесли queue как класс и нужно самому его создавать ?

Comment: Это не обычный c++ а c++/cli подробнее: https://habr.com/ru/post/111071/, А лучше используйте c# проще будет, там есть графичекий редактор интерфейса.

Comment: Всегда говорил и скажу ещё раз: передайте вашим преподам, которые заставляют вас писать приложения на C++/CLI, что они редиски. Покажите им мой комментарий. Иначе так и будете учить ненужное.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov лучший коммент. А подскажите графический редактор или платформу для разработки графического интерфейса под язык с++ ?

Comment: Зарубите себе на носу: C++ и C++/CLI - это два **разных** языка. Определитесь, какой вы учите?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov учу я с++.

Comment: Тогда не пользуйтесь Visual Studio. Это превосходная IDE, но проблема с ней в том, что она позволяет создавать проекты и на C++, и на C++/CLI. Начинающие постоянно путаются. Снесите её! Используйте любую другую IDE для освоения C++.

Comment: WinForms - это проект на C++/CLI (CLR). | И вообще, забудьте пока про создание графических интерфейсов. Вам нужно азы языка освоить. Банально ту же работу со стандартной библиотекой (STL), в составе которой есть и очереди.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, хорошо , спасибо за ответ :3

Comment: @Cipher если уж очень хочется в графику, попробуйте C#. Его проще осваивать, хоть и языки разной направленности, и переходить потом на С++ имея базу тоже будет проще

Comment: @SelfishCrawler, хорошо , попробую